Meta description is not showing in Google search results
Some of my meta descriptions are now missing, whereas just a few weeks ago, they were in the right place. However, within the past few days, they seem to have disappeared.

I have tried re-indexing, clearing cached URLs and even shorting the previous meta descriptions.

This is similar to When is meta description still relevant? but in that case, Google is choosing a snippet in place of the meta description.  In this case neither meta description or snippet is showing up.

Per Google's documentation, Open Graph meta elements are not specifically used. So it is best to use what is listed in their documentation in order to have the best chance for them to appear in the SERP.

The page I looked at had invalid markup.
It should be meta name="description" and not meta property="description".
See - https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-meta-element.html

I think those are for the OpenGraph tags for sharing on socials. So I believe those are correct but you are also correct that they are missing the <meta name="description"> tag that usually points out the description.

The page I looked at had both tags (plus Twitter), though it may be completely lacking on other pages.

I looked at his home page and there was only the og tags.
